# Chess game optimization: inefficient performance despite attack tiles update

Tags: java, chess

I am developing a chess game and recently made a change in my code to optimize move generation by updating attack tiles and pins more efficiently. Initially, I used to calculate the attack tiles for the enemy side every time I generated moves. However, I modified the code to calculate this information once during the initialization of the **Board** object and then update the relevant squares as needed during each move.

Here is the update function and the relevant data structures:

```
private HashMap<Integer, List<List<List<Integer>>>> attackedTiles;
private HashMap<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> pins;

private void updateAttackedTilesAndPins(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    int[] colors = new int[]{Piece.WHITE, Piece.BLACK};
    int pieceIndex = Piece.index(tile[newIndex]);

    for (int color : colors) {
        List<List<List<Integer>>> attackedTilesColor = attackedTiles.get(color);

        for (int i = 0; i < attackedTilesColor.size(); i++) {
            //no point in looking at the moved piece, since we will recalculate the attacked tiles for it anyway
            if (i == pieceIndex) {
                continue;
            }

            //update every line of sight that could see the moved piece
            for (List<Integer> lineOfSight : attackedTilesColor.get(i)) {
                if (lineOfSight.contains(oldIndex) || lineOfSight.contains(newIndex)) {
                    updateLineOfSight(lineOfSight);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //calculate the attacked tiles for the moved piece
    attackedTiles.get(turn).set(pieceIndex, calculateAttackedTiles(newIndex));

    pins.get(turn).clear();

    //check if any piece is pinning anything
    List<Integer> piecePositionsTurn = piecePositions.get(turn);
    for (int piecePosition : piecePositionsTurn) {
        if (piecePosition == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        List<Integer> pinLine = calculatePinLine(piecePosition);
        if (!pinLine.isEmpty()) {
            pins.get(turn).add(pinLine);
        }
    }
}
```

I know attackedTiles is ugly, so here is what it might look like, where each inner list is a line of sight of a piece in a direction:

```
Attacked tiles white:
[[48, 41]]
[[58, 49], [58, 51]]
[[59, 50], [59, 51], [59, 52], [59, 58], [59, 60]]
[[60, 51], [60, 52], [60, 53], [60, 59], [60, 61]]
[[61, 52], [61, 54]]
[[62, 45], [62, 47], [62, 52]]
[[63, 55], [63, 62]]
Attacked tiles black:
[[0, 1], [0, 8]]
[[1, 11], [1, 16], [1, 18]]
[[2, 9], [2, 11]]
[[3, 2], [3, 4], [3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12]]
[[4, 3], [4, 5], [4, 11], [4, 12], [4, 13]]
[[5, 12], [5, 14]]
[[6, 12], [6, 21], [6, 23]]
```

I had a lot of faith in this approach, because I felt like it should be faster than before. After running some test I found that it is just as fast. Not slower, not faster. Which I don't really understand.

I did run a profiler though and these are the results
[image: Profiler results]

From what I can tell, the update function itself is causing slowdowns, not the child functions. I am wondering if my approach is flawed or if I am making inefficient use of cache locality. The attackedTiles data structure might not be the most elegant, but is it also slow to iterate through? Do I just need a more efficient version of checking if a piece is seen by another, so that maybe I can prune that list or something and I don't have to look at it?

Comment: Have you tried to use the stream(), filter(), and forEach() operations to replace traditional loops and conditionals where applicable?

Comment: @jvatechs I tried what was suggested in an answer below, but that actually slowed me down

Comment: Try changing the inner lists from `List<Integer>` to `int[2]`. Primitives are generally a bit faster than boxed objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **certainly not entirely sure** about the significant increase in efficiency but I think you should to try the manipulations and see what'll happen.
I changed the 2 parts of your code:

```
    //update every line of sight that could see the moved piece
    for (List<Integer> lineOfSight : attackedTilesColor.get(i)) {
        if (lineOfSight.contains(oldIndex) || lineOfSight.contains(newIndex)) {
            updateLineOfSight(lineOfSight);
        }
    }

    //check if any piece is pinning anything
    List<Integer> piecePositionsTurn = piecePositions.get(turn);
    for (int piecePosition : piecePositionsTurn) {
        if (piecePosition == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        List<Integer> pinLine = calculatePinLine(piecePosition);
        if (!pinLine.isEmpty()) {
            pins.get(turn).add(pinLine);
        }
    }
```

and transformed it into `.stream()`:

```
//update every line of sight that could see the moved piece
attackedTilesColor.get(i).stream()
        .filter(lineOfSight -> lineOfSight.contains(oldIndex) || lineOfSight.contains(newIndex))
        .forEach(this::updateLineOfSight);

//check if any piece is pinning anything
piecePositions.get(turn).stream()
        .filter(piecePosition -> piecePosition != -1)
        .map(this::calculatePinLine)
        .filter(pinLine -> !pinLine.isEmpty())
        .forEach(pins.get(turn)::add);
```

### **UPDATE:**

Let's try this with replaced `List<List<List<Integer>>>` to `List<Set<List<Integer>>>` for `attackedTiles`because  `Set` has a time complexity of `O(1)` for this operation, compared to `O(n)` for `List`  :

```
private HashMap<Integer, List<Set<List<Integer>>>> attackedTiles;
private HashMap<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> pins;

private void updateAttackedTilesAndPins(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    int[] colors = new int[]{Piece.WHITE, Piece.BLACK};
    int pieceIndex = Piece.index(tile[newIndex]);

    for (int color : colors) {
        List<Set<List<Integer>>> attackedTilesColor = attackedTiles.get(color);

        for (int i = 0; i < attackedTilesColor.size(); i++) {
            if (i == pieceIndex) {
                continue;
            }

            //update every line of sight that could see the moved piece
            Set<List<Integer>> linesOfSight = attackedTilesColor.get(i);
            for (List<Integer> lineOfSight : linesOfSight) {
                if (lineOfSight.contains(oldIndex) || lineOfSight.contains(newIndex)) {
                    updateLineOfSight(lineOfSight);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //calculate the attacked tiles for the moved piece
    attackedTiles.get(turn).set(pieceIndex, new HashSet<>(calculateAttackedTiles(newIndex)));

    pins.get(turn).clear();

    List<Integer> piecePositionsTurn = piecePositions.get(turn);
    for (int piecePosition : piecePositionsTurn) {
        if (piecePosition == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        List<Integer> pinLine = calculatePinLine(piecePosition);
        if (!pinLine.isEmpty()) {
            pins.get(turn).add(pinLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually slowed me down by about 35%

Comment: @Popo okay, let's try replace ``List<List<List<Integer>>>`` with ``List<Set<List<Integer>>>`` for ``attackedTiles``. This change should make the contains operation faster because ``Set`` has a time complexity of ``O(1)`` for this operation, compared to ``O(n)`` for ``List``.